# Multiple form onsubmit validations?

Tags: javascript

I have a form and currently I have a javascript code to validate my form to make sure that the user fills out every input. my form action includes:

```
onsubmit="return validateForm();"
```

Which is the javascript to make sure every field is filled out. If it makes any difference, here is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// 
<![CDATA[function validateForm() { 
    var a=document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_FirstName"].value; 
    var b=document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_Email"].value; 
    var c=document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_Phone1"].value; 
    if (a==null || a=="" || a=="First Name Here")
    {   alert("Please enter your First Name!");   
    return false;   }     
    if (c==null || c==''|| c=="Enter Your Phone Here")
    {    alert("Please insert your phone number!");   
    return false;   }    
    var emailRegEx = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;    
    if (document.myform.inf_field_Email.value.search(emailRegEx) == -1)  
    {           alert("Please enter a valid email address.");               
    return false;    } }
    // ]]>
</script>
```

However on the phone number field, defined at c, I want to add another script that will pop up if the user doesn't enter a phone number at least 9 digits long. I was thinking of adding a code like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(){

var c=document.forms["myform"]
    if (input.length<9){
        alert("Please enter a real phone number")
        return false
    }else {
        return true
    }
}
</script>
```

However I don't know how to run both functions on submit.  I am extremely new to javascript so excuse me if there's already a simple solution to this.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just add an `else if` to the phone number check in your existing `validateForm()` function?

Comment: Why not use another regex for phone number? `if ( /^\d{9}$/.test( c ) )`. Also btw, `A-Z0-9_/i == \w`

Answer (score 1):

Everything in quotes after onsubmit= is just javascript.  You can make sure both functions return true by doing:

```
onsubmit="return validateForm() && validate();"
```

Comment: @Yve  The onsubmit is a javascript line of code, and it is good practice to put a semicolon at the end of each line.  Although it will work without one, you should have it for good programming standards.

Comment: You're welcome.  There's always something new to learn with programming, that's why I love it!

Answer (score 0):

You could add it as another rule in that conditional. For example:

```
if (c==null || c==''|| c=="Enter Your Phone Here" || c.length < 9)   {    
  alert("Please insert your phone number!");   
  return false;
}
```

It's probably best to refactor this code, but that's probably the fastest way to do what you need.